# IOS Segue not able to set label directly

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am having two view controllers 'FirstViewController' and 'SecondViewController'. From first view controller it will take input from a text field ,process it and display accordingly in the second view. But I am having a problem while setting label value directly.

```
   @interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
    {
        NSString *numPlate;
        IBOutlet UILabel *output;
    };
    @property(strong,nonatomic) NSString *numPlate;
    @property(strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *output;
    @end
```

The main file for FirstViewController.m with prepare for segue is as

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Change"])
    {
       SecondViewController *svc = (SecondViewController *)[segue            destinationViewController]; 
       svc.numPlate = input.text;


       NumberPlate *numPlate=[[NumberPlate alloc]init];
       [numPlate setPlate:input.text];
       NSInteger flag=[numPlate checkValidity];
       if(flag==0)
       {
           svc.output.text  =@"Invalid License";
       }
       else
       if([numPlate getArea]==NULL||[numPlate getRegOffice]==NULL)
       {
            svc.output.text  =@"Data not found";
       }
       else
       {
        svc.output.text  =@"VALID License";
       }
     }
   }
```

But when the action is performed its not working.The label is not changing.
When i used svc.numPlate instead of svc.output.text and in the SecondViewController viewDidLoad method and i used

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
     output.text=numPlate;
}
```

Everything is fine with this. Whats wrong in first method??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to assign value directly to `UILabel` of second VC **as view is not yet loaded into view hierarchy** at this point.

So view cannot render the value assigned prior to it.

On the other hand, holding value in `NSString` and assigning same on `viewDidLoad` is working as now your view is in view hierarchy and loaded into memory.

Comment: Thanks,Is there any better method than passing data to a string.

Comment: @BittuAby in a way this is the solution rather having globals or static for passing value.

Comment: I am new to ios programming. Can you give me some tutorial links on these topics. ie globals /statics

Answer (score 1):

At the time when you push SecondViewController, the SecondViewController's view hasn't been loaded yet, so you can't access its views. You need to create NSString properties in SecondViewController and pass a string to SecondViewController' NSString Object. Then in SecondViewController's viewDidLoad method, use those properties to populate the labels (which will have been loaded by the time viewDidLoad runs).

Answer (score 0):

The initialisation of controller is different and presentation of its view is different process even if the viewController has been initialise its view will not because pushing the controller has not performed and controller dont know he need to load the view.. so we pass the data to controller and it load when view appears... like below code

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController{
   NSString *strMessage;

}
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *strMessage;

@end
SecondViewController.m

@synthesize strMessage;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
Nslog(@"%@",strMessage);
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Change"])
     {
      SecondViewController *svc = (SecondViewController *)[segue          destinationViewController]; 


    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Check out %@", nameLb.text];
    svc.strMessage=message;
}
```